# Shortcuts for language switching issue on Ubuntu 18.04 vs Windows

Tags: keyboard, multi-boot, keyboard-layout, shortcuts, ubuntu-18.04

For a long time, I was a user of Windows 10, but recently installed a second OS - Ubuntu 18.04.

For me, the best way to switch language is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, so I'd like to stay with it on both systems.

The problem I noticed is that on Windows language switches after shortcut keys are released, while on Ubuntu after shortcut keys are pressed. So when I want to use another shortcut (e.g. anonymous window in chrome - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) - on Windows, it successfully opens, but on Ubuntu it doesn't, because after pressing the first two keys of shortcuts it simply changes the language.

Is there any way to change shortcuts activation behavior, so it changes language when the shortcut is released, but not pressed?

Or maybe there is some other way to resolve this problem?